# How to enable or disable option of legend in fusion chart

Tags: legend, fusioncharts

I´m using fusion chart, and i need to use external legend like a checkbox.

How can i enabled or disable options of my chart, from the checkbox ?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Do you want a `checkbox` to enable or disable legend interactivity?

Comment: hi !!!, i need to enabled or disabled items on the graph. no the legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the FusionCharts JavaScript class to update the data on event strike.

For more information on updating the chart, visit-

http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/JavaScript/JS_ChangeData.html#update

The attribute 'visible' of the  element can be used for this purpose to show and to hide the data plot.

Comment: Additionally, to remove the legend interactivity by, 'interactiveLegend' attribute and hide it by using 'showLegend' attribute

Comment: Check this http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/features/#client-side-update-of-data

Comment: Just for the record the visible attribute on the dataset only works for JS charts, not SWF charts. v3.3.1 forward  http://forum.fusioncharts.com/topic/9750-hide-dataset-in-chart-by-default/?p=55792

Comment: Some differences are there in Flash and JS rendering.